Why shouldn't we manually add paths to `sys.path`?
I read in multiple sources that it is not recommended to manually add paths to the list of paths sys.path that the Python interpreter checks when it encounters an import statement. However, I was not able to understand the reasons they gave, like "hard to maintain", so I am turning to you.
I can understand that having packages (i.e. libraries) that were built by other people saved in non-standard directories (i.e. folders) on your PC, and then adding those directories to sys.path (either by directly appending the list, or indirectly by adding the paths to the environment variable PYTHONPATH) is considered as bad practice. I heard some people doing it because they want to have a location on their PC where they keep track of packages (i.e. libraries) which they think that will not be used at the time when the project gets deployed.
Luckily, today we have software that can act as package managers that give you an opportunity to keep track of 'dev' packages (i.e. packages which you just need during development, but you will not need when you deploy your code) like poetry.
The thing which I can't understand is why would it be considered a bad practice to add a path to the root directory (i.e. folder) of your project to sys.path (either directly or indirectly), as long as the code for doing that is written to be non-specifc to your PC. The root directory (i.e. folder) of a project is most often the current-working-directory (i.e. cwd), which is why it is important to have it in the list of paths sys.path, in order to be able to allow you to write import statements that are relative to it. - this is my opinion, not a hard fact, so please challenge it
Again, I understand that if you add the path that leads to the root directory (i.e. folder) of your project into sys.path by either:

explicitly inputting the path in the environment variable PYTHONPATH, or
explicitly inputting the path through code to the list of paths sys.path using the function append(...) (i.e. by using the syntax sys.path.append(absoluePathWhichIsPCSpecific))
you would make the code specific to your local PC, and then the code you wrote would (almost certainly) not work on other PC-s.

However, I don't understand why it would be considered a bad practice to use code that would add the path to the current-working-directy (i.e. cwd) if it is made non-specific to your local setup. For example, you could input the following code into a module (i.e. a file with the extension .py):
import os import sys if(os.getcwd() not in sys.path) sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
Adding the code above to a module would allow you to run the module with a shell-command such as python folderOne/folderTwo/nameOfModule, and be able to use import-statements in the module nameOfModule.py which are relative to the root directory (i.e. folder) of your project. This will be true if we assume that you run code from the root directory (i.e. folder), but this is fair to assume because whenever you use an IDE and open a project from folder, the root directory (i.e. folder) is the cwd.
Could you please elaborate on the reasons why changing the list of path sys.path is commonly considered as bad practice using an example? Also, please give me an alternative to what should someone do if they want to run a module from the root directory (i.e. folder) of a project, if a module is saved in a sub-folder (or a sub-sub-folder), without using relative-imports which are considered as bad practice (at least I consider them as such).
